# Is $\lim\limits_{x,y\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt x\sqrt y}{\sqrt{xy}}=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity, indeterminate-forms

WolframAlpha is suggesting (judging by the plot given) that [the limit is actually $-1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E1%2F2+y%5E1%2F2+%2F+%28xy%29%5E1%2F2).

I would think the following manipulations would be okay to conclude that is the opposite.
$$\lim_{x,y\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt x\sqrt y}{\sqrt{xy}}=\lim_{x,y\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt x\sqrt y}{\sqrt x\sqrt y}=\lim_{x,y\to-\infty}1=1$$
I usually trust WA's conclusions about things like this, so I'm fairly certain I'm missing something, obvious or otherwise.

Comment: Are $x, y$ tending to MINUS $\infty$? If so, then $\sqrt{x}$, $\sqrt{y}$ are undefined.

Comment: Ah, that explains where my reasoning went wrong. But why is the limit $-1$?

Comment: The limit is not $-1$. There is no limit, because there is no well-defined square root on the negative numbers.

Comment: If one goes to complex numbers, **and** takes the principal branches of the square roots, then indeed we get $-1$. (Wolfram Alpha is complex numbers fixated.)

Comment: Yup, I'm seeing it now. Rookie mistake on my part.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Still, what's the definition of $x\longrightarrow -\infty$ for $x\in\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Here for WA $x$ goes to $-\infty$ along the reals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist that $\sqrt 1=1$ and $\sqrt {-1}=i$ then $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt x\sqrt y$ does not always hold, for example when $x=y=-1$.

Comment: Right, so my reasoning is flawed, thanks for pointing out why

Answer (score 3):

It is common for a CAS like WA to definitively take the square root of a negative real to be the imaginary square root with positive imaginary component. So WA is probably seeing $$\frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{xy}}=\frac{(i\sqrt{|x|})(i\sqrt{|y|})}{\sqrt{xy}}=-\frac{\sqrt{|x||y|}}{\sqrt{xy}}=-1$$ where throughout, keep reminding yourself both $x$ and $y$ are negative.

Comment: This is spot on!  +1 I was going to post this as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Hagen's answer. We can use the principle branch of the square root and say that $u=-x$, giving us $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \sqrt x = \lim_{u\to\infty} \sqrt{-1}\sqrt u = \lim_{u\to\infty} i\sqrt u$

and $v = -y$ giving us $\lim_{v\to\infty} i\sqrt v$

But we also have $lim_{x,y\to-\infty}\sqrt{xy} = lim_{u,v\to\infty}\sqrt{uv} $

This gives us $$\lim_{x,y\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt x\sqrt y}{\sqrt{xy}} = i^2 \lim_{u,v\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt u\sqrt v}{\sqrt{uv}}=-\lim_{u,v\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt u\sqrt v}{\sqrt{uv}}= -1$$